# How do I conditionally create a new instance of a class in C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class with different constructors. One constructor, nothing is passed through (creating a new record), the other an ID is passed through (which is used for an update). I'd like to test for a condition and make a new instance of the class object based on the outcome. My problem is that the object doesn't carry out of the if statement.

```
protected void Position()
{
    if (Session["PositionID"] == null)
    {
        JobPosition p = new JobPosition();
    }
    else
    { 
        JobPosition p = new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(Session["PositionID"]));
    }
    p.positionTitle= pTitle.text;
    p.positionMission= pMission.text;
    p.positionDepartment= pDept.text;
    Session["PositionID"] = Convert.ToString(p.SaveDB());   
}
```

p cannot be used in the current context. I could copy my code into each condition, it just seems like I shouldn't need to do that.

How can I use `p`?

Comment: Remember to consider [C# block scope](http://pro-thoughts.blogspot.com/2008/05/c-block-ccoping-rules-for-variables.html) (See also [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0020__Language-Basics/Blockscope.htm)) (everyone else posted the answer, I might as well explain _why_ it's the answer).

Comment: You can safely remove the second block of code where you're dealing with the SQL side of things.  It doesn't apply to your problem and only clutters up the question. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of `p` to above the if statement:

```
JobPosition p;

if (Session["PositionID"] == null)
{
    p = new JobPosition();
}
else
{ 
    p = new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(Session["PositionID"]));
}
```

If you declare a variable inside a local scope, it is not accessible when you leave that scope.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but it seems like you want:

```
protected void Position()
{
    JobPosition p;
    if (Session["PositionID"] == null)
    {
        p = new JobPosition();
    }
    else
    { 
        p = new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(Session["PositionID"]));
    }
    p.positionTitle= pTitle.text;
    p.positionMission= pMission.text;
    p.positionDepartment= pDept.text;
    Session["PositionID"] = Convert.ToString(p.SaveDB());   
}
```

Comment: An upvote for being the answer that correctly (IMO) doesn't assign a null value to p in the declaration.

Comment: Yea, as long as you make sure it is assigned in all branches, it's redundant to assign it a default value.  I have co-workers that do that stuff, drives me bonkers.

Comment: I suppose it's just habit, to stop the compiler warning that you usually get (Just not in this instance).

Answer (score 2):

Move the `JobPosition` declaration outside the conditional.

Comment: No need to set to null; in fact, *not* setting it to anything is better, as the compiler then ensures that all branches *do* assign it (assuming it is used later on).

Comment: Can you explain why he would set it to null? In his binary approach, it's a useless assignment. Marc also raises a good point about the benefit of *not* setting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Position()
{
   JobPosition p; // No need for null;
   if (Session["PositionID"] == null)
    {
        p = new JobPosition();
    }
    else
    { 
        p = new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(Session["PositionID"]));
    }

    // Don't need to check if p is null again here too
        p.positionTitle= pTitle.text;
        p.positionMission= pMission.text;
        p.positionDepartment= pDept.text;
        Session["PositionID"] = Convert.ToString(p.SaveDB()); 

}
```

Comment: No need to initialize to null (see also my comment on George's answer)

Comment: @MarcGravell doesn't VS give a compile time error if you don't, afaik it would

Comment: @kd7, it would not. The compiler can see that you assign it in the `if` *and* the `else`, so it can prove `p` is assigned and would not raise an error. If the code was instead `if (a) { p = ...;} else if (b) { p = ...; }`, then no definite assignment could be proved, because both `a` and `b` could be false.

Answer (score 1):

Move p out of the if/else scope into the method scope.

```
JobPosition p = null;

if (Session["PositionID"] == null)
{
    p = new JobPosition();
}
else
{ 
    p = new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(Session["PositionID"]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare JobPosition outside the if block:

```
JobPosition p;
if (Session["PositionID"] == null)
{
    p = new JobPosition();
}
else
{
    p = new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(Session["PositionID"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
JobPosition p = null;
if (Session["PositionID"] == null)
{
    p = new JobPosition();
}
else
{ 
    p = new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(Session["PositionID"]));
}
```

The `null` isn't strictly needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Position() 
{ 
    JobPosition p = null; //declare only once
    if (Session["PositionID"] == null) 
    { 
        p = new JobPosition(); 
    } 
    else 
    {  
        p = new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(Session["PositionID"])); 
    } 
    p.positionTitle= pTitle.text; 
    p.positionMission= pMission.text; 
    p.positionDepartment= pDept.text; 
    Session["PositionID"] = Convert.ToString(p.SaveDB());    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be more inclined to do the following.

```
    protected void Position()
    {
        const string positionIdKey = "PositionID";
        var positionId = Session[positionIdKey];
        var p = positionId == null 
            ? new JobPosition() 
            : new JobPosition(Convert.ToInt32(positionId));
        p.Update(pTitle.text, pMission.text, pDept.text);
        Session[positionIdKey] = p.SaveDB();
    }
```